# Percorrer gradiente de cor de acordo com o valor

Tags: javascript, html, css

Preciso representar a temperatura de um local usando cores, a temperatura mais baixa devo representar com azul, o intermediário com amarelo e a mais alta com vermelho.

Mas não posso simplesmente fixar apenas estas 3 cores, gostaria de ter uma transição mais suave entre as trocas de temperatura, eu quero percorrer um gradiente de cor de acordo com o valor que eu assumir

Eu quero pintar uma div de acordo com o valor que a temperatura daquele depósito estiver representando

30_____________________________________0_______________________________________-30
[image: Gradiente de cor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos pegar como faixa de valores, 0 a 100 graus Celsius.

100 graus é o mais quente, portanto deve aparecer vermelho, RGB (255,0,0)
0 grau é o mais frio, deve aparecer azul, RGB (0,0,255)

Sendo assim, calculamos um coeficiente, que é a relação do 100 com 255. Dividindo dá 2.55, ou seja, quando a temperatura estiver em 100 (máximo), multiplicamos por 2.55 para chegar a 255, o valor do RGB máximo. Precisamos agora inverter os valores, quando um aumenta, o outro diminui. Para isso, podemos somar ou subtrair 255. Vou calcular diretamente o valor do Red e inverter o valor do Blue subtraindo 255.

Para demonstrar, vamos usar um controle tipe "range" e um um pouco de `javascript` para alterar a cor conforme o valor do controle muda:

```js
$('#temp').on("change", function(){
  // como a faixa vai de 0 a 100, calcula o valor atual da cor:
  var coeficiente = 255/100; //2.55, ou seja, 100C corresponde a 255
  var temperatura = $(this).val();
  /*
   como 0 grau é o mais frio e 100 graus o mais quente,
   calcula o valor do red e o do blue no RGB
   Quente R=255, B=0
   Frio R=0, B=255
   
   Para chegar nesses valores, multiplicaos o coeficiente pelo valor da cor
   Como precisa inverter os valores (quando um for 0 o outro será 255),
   basta subtrair por 255 ou somar por 255
   Fiz o cálculo do azul subraindo 255, e como será negativo, multipliquei por -1
  */
  var red  =  (temperatura * coeficiente);
  var blue =  ((temperatura * coeficiente)-255)*-1;
  var cor = "rgb(" + red + ",0," + blue + ")";
  $('#temp-cor').css("background-color", cor);
})
```

```css
#temp-cor {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  background-color: RGB(128,0,128);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>Temperatura:</span>
  0<input id="temp" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50">100
 
</div>
<div id="temp-cor"></div>
```

Fiz esse exemplo usando apenas o vermelho e azul, mas pode seguir a mesma ideia e calcular o verde e fazer o espectro de cores mais vivo, mas a ideia é a mesma.